# Minimize a strictly convex quadratic function subject to linearly equality and nonnegativity constraints in finite time?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am wondering if we can minimize a strictly convex quadratic function in finite time, subject to linearly equality and nonnegativity constraints.

Thanks!

Comment: As a practical matter, such problems are relatively easy to solve numerically to within reasonable tolerances.  However, it sounds as though you're asking a more theoretical question about exactly solving the problem within some model of computation.  What computational model are you interested in?

Comment: Thanks Brian. Yes, I am asking this from a theoretical perspective. I am wondering if it is possible to use convex optimization techniques to solve this one in polynomial time or finite time (if polynomial is not achievable).

Comment: @XiMS: As Brian asked: "what model of computation are you using?" Complexity analysis depends on the model of computation----the term "polynomial time" too, so it would be good to know what model. But in the commonly used oracle model, the runtimes are polynomial in the problem size for $\epsilon$-accuracy solution (depending on stuff like $1/\epsilon$, $\log(1/\epsilon)$, etc.)

Comment: @Suvrit, thank you so much! I see. I think I am talking about the oracle model. I was reading the book "Convex Optimization" by Professor Stephen Boyd yesterday. I think many ϵ-accuracy solutions mentioned (like Newton's step in that book) are actually based on the oracle model.

Comment: @Xims: you'll benefit greatly by reading the book: *Introductory lectures on convex optimization* by Yurii Nesterov --- that books a very nice introduction to oracle based complexity (upper and lower bounds); you can also have a look at Lecture 23 of my course: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~suvrit/teach/aopt.html

Comment: @Suvrit, thanks a lot! I really appreciate this. I am reading:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although complexity analysis can give you some insight on the difficulty of your problem, it is unlikely that will settle your question in full-generality.

For example: in the oracle model, a strongly convex function can be minimized in time $O(\ln(1/\varepsilon))$. However, since your domain is a general polyhedron, it depends on how easy is to solve projections (or computing Prox-mappings) over your polyhedron to obtain good running time.

My advice is: have a look at Nesterov's book (as suggested above) to see if his optimal method is applicable to your problem (this gives you $O(1/T^2)$ convergence rate). If your polyhedral domain is complicated, you might want to try a Frank-Wolfe method, that does not require projection (or proximal) computations, and converges at the rate $O(1/T)$. Finally, since your objective is strongly convex, these methods can be applied with 'restarts' so you can obtain the much better convergence rate $O(e^{-T})$ (e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4666).

Finally, I think it is very unlikely that you find good lower bounds for your problem for general polyhedral sets; moreover, this analysis depends crucially on how you access your data. For example, if your oracle is only able to solve LPs, then there are simple lower bounding techniques (http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5550). If your oracle only is constrained to be 'local', the complexity can have a different behavior (http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5001).

Comment: Cristobal: as far as I can tell, the problem posed by the OP can be solved with a method that converges at a linear rate (by passing to an ADMM procedure to "easily" handle the linear constraints).

Comment: Suvrit: that is indeed true, but I wanted to point out that computing Prox-mappings might not even be necessary by the striking result of Garber and Hazan. Also I thought it was necessary to explain that complexity theory would probably not give the ultimate answer (e.g., one needs to incorporate the cost of your oracle as well).

Comment: Indeed Cristóbal: I just commented to point out one more small addition to your already nice answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, guys. This is quite helpful! I am reading the docs you pointed out.